# Can you Dash twice on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

The Dash action gives you extra movement for the current turn (equal to your speed). If I have an effect (like the *Expeditious Retreat* spell or the monk's Step of the Wind feature) which allows me to dash as a bonus action, can I *also* dash as my regular action, for triple movement?

Comment: Not asked, but you by the answer given you could even quintuple move with action surge and haste action.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Yes.](https://thesageadvice.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/the-fastest-rogue/)

If you can dash as a bonus action you can move, dash, and then dash again, moving thrice your speed in a round.

There is no stipulation on Dash that you can't use it as an action (if you have the ability to do so) if you've taken it as your bonus action (like there is with casting a spell as a bonus action).

Comment: @MonkeezOnFire That link is dead, but here is tweet from Jeremy Crawford to the same effect: https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/564971297831010304

Comment: And JC tweets are official ruling anymore, but the answer is the same.

Comment: @J.A.Streich Did you miss a negative in that comment? JC's tweets are no longer official rulings.

Comment: Lol.  I know I typed not or aren't.....  But yes, I missed a negative.  JC's tweets **aren't** official anymore.  It has been a pain in my butt for a while as mods keep finding my old answers.