# Can a Rogue effectively triple their speed by combining Dash and Ready, spreading it over several turns?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions, rogue, readied-action

This question is a follow-up to:

[Can you move on your turn, and then use the Ready Action to move again on another creature's turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148815/can-you-move-on-your-turn-and-then-use-the-ready-action-to-move-again-on-anoth)

The answer to that question is **yes**. Acting according to the following sequence should then enable a rogue (of at least second level) to **triple** their maximum movement in one round, right?

1. Bonus Action: Cunning Action -> Dash
2. Movement: move twice your speed
3. Action: ready additional movement
4. Reaction: move your speed

To clarify: The idea was **not** to move as far as possible on your own turn (which can be more easily achieved by simply taking Dash as a Bonus Action and as an Action, as was pointed out to me in the answers), but to spread your movement over several turns by using the reaction.

Comment: Related (but not dupe because this one asks about the Ready action): [How far does a rogue move when dashing twice using Cunning Action?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57340)

Comment: related: [fastest 5e character(s)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58632/23970)

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Can you Dash twice on the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48213/can-you-dash-twice-on-the-same-turn)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Yes a rogue can move three times their movement in one round

A rogue could:

1. Use their full normal movement speed.
2. Use '[Cunning Action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#CunningAction-345)' to Dash for a Bonus Action, moving your full movement speed again.
3. Use the Ready action to prepare to move again. Then if your specified trigger is met, use your reaction to move your full movement once more.

That's fine, they've moved three times their movement speed in one round - job done.

**However, it's also unnecessarily complicated.**

If you just want to move as far as possible, then instead of readying an action to move, in step three, you could simply use your normal action to dash, on your turn, as well as using your bonus action.

[Dash](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dash) is an action which is always available, to any character, to take on their turn. The Rogue's special feature is their ability to do it as a bonus action as well (note Cunning Action is not the only way to get this ability).

**Using the Dash action rather than the Ready action has a couple of advantages**. Firstly, it means your third move is guaranteed, rather than reliant on a trigger for your readied action, which might not come. Secondly, it leaves your reaction free to be used elsewhere - say for an attack of opportunity.

Answer (score 39):

## Yes, and they don't need to ready an action to do it

Say their movement is **30ft**. They expend their movement for 30ft, use their action to Dash for an extra 30ft, then Bonus action to Dash again with an additional 30ft.

**90ft** in total - **triple** their base movement

Here's a question that covers Dashing twice on the same round:

[Can you dash twice on the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48213/can-you-dash-twice-on-the-same-turn?rq=1)

Comment: Hi - Yes that's right you can still ready an action to split up movement over the round, but that portion of the question was already covered by the [first question you linked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148815/can-you-move-on-your-turn-and-then-use-the-ready-action-to-move-again-on-anothe) so I focused on whether it was possible

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, this works...but is more complicated than it needs to be.

There is no rule that says you can only use the same Action once on your turn.

Dash simply does this...

> When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers.

[source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Dash)

So there is no need to muck about with the Ready Action...you can simply do the following.

Base speed: 30 feet.
Bonus Action: Cunning Action -> Dash +30 feet.
Action: Dash +30 feet.
Total Movement this round: 90 feet.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes and with no need for ready actions either.

And If I'm understanding the rules correctly, under the right circumstances you could potentially move 4 times your speed. You would need to multiclass to get action surge but how it would work would be:

Move your base speed: 30 feet.

Bonus Action: Cunning Action -> Dash +30 feet. (total 60 feet, 2x movement)

Action: Dash +30 feet. (total 90 feet, 3x movement)

Action Surge

Second Action: Dash +30 feet. (total 120 feet, 4x movement)

So a level 4 (2 rogue/2 fighter) character with a base move speed of 30 could move 120 feet over 6 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.